# Change long if statement to LINQ

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I wrote this check in C# to perform some value checking:

```
           if ((x <= 20 && y <= 5) || (x <= 30 && y <= 10) ||
           (x <= 50 && y <= 15) || (x <= 70 && y <= 20) ||
           (x <= 70 && y <= 30))
             {
                // do something
              }
```

I'm in the process to learn LINQ, and I would like to change the above code to use LINQ,

If you submit a code, can you please add some comment to explain the conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really wanted to use LINQ, one way would be to store a collection of tuples that represented each of the cases (upper-bounds) and then use the [**`Enumerable.Any`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) method to test  if an `(x, y)` pair met any of the possible conditions.

Example (in reality, you can create the collection once and give it longer lifetime, perhaps through a field-reference):

```
var bounds = new Dictionary<int, int>
{
    {20, 5},
    {30, 10},
    {50, 15},
    {70, 20},
    {70, 30}
}.Select(kvp => new { XUpperBound = kvp.Key, YUpperBound = kvp.Value });


if (bounds.Any(tuple => x <= tuple.XUpperBound && y <= tuple.YUpperBound))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: So...move overhead, longer, and more difficult to read, all for the sake of using the `Select` statement?

Comment: @Adam Oh come on. It's answering the original question ;) +1 for a creative answer

Comment: It's definitely a case of "LINQ doesn't help here and can make it uglier" but an interesting solution to an academic problem.

Comment: @Adam: The `Select` isn't important, it's only to turn the KVPs into a more meaningful tuple-wrapper. You can get rid of it and do `kvp => x <= kvp.Key && y <= kvp.Value` if you want. The answer is about using `Any` instead of a bunch of `||`s. I'm not claiming that I would write the code this way, but the OP did ask for a LINQ solution.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ doesn't have anything to do with the code that you've posted. Since the numbers you've chosen seem to be largely arbitrary, I don't see a way of reducing that statement any further.

To make it look better, just format the code:

```
if  (
    (x <= 20 && y <= 5) || 
    (x <= 30 && y <= 10) ||
    (x <= 50 && y <= 15) || 
    (x <= 70 && y <= 20) ||
    (x <= 70 && y <= 30)
    )
        {
            // do something
        }
```

This should make your pairs clear, make it easy to add conditions, while not adding the overhead of LINQ just for the sake of using it.

Comment: @Mark: What needs enhancing? The code is clear, though `x` and `y` are decidedly oblique variable names.

Comment: What if I need to change the numbers to compare to, or when there is a need to add more pairs comparison?

Comment: @Mark: I think that can be solved through formatting rather than changing to something like LINQ. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks, I actually did end up using the same code, but because I actually did ask for LINQ, I selected Ani as an answer.

Comment: @Mark: So my answer solved your problem, but you selected a different answer to accept?